# How to add response headers to data-urls by Chrome.webRequest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I according to the [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) I want to change data-urls responseheaders.But I can't capture data request in `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived`.

Am I wrong ?

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function (details) {
    const url = details.url

    if(url == 'http://www.example.com/api/getUsers') {
      return {
        redirectUrl: 'data:application/json; charset=utf-8,' + 
JSON.stringify({"a":1, "b": 2})
      }
    }

    return {cancel: false}

  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking"]
)

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function (details) {
    console.log(details)  // can't capture data-urls

    return {responseHeaders:details.responseHeaders};
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["responseHeaders","blocking"]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't capture `data:` URLs with `webRequest` API, since `data:` is not a [supported scheme for host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns#toc).

As such, even with `<all_urls>` permission/filter you won't get events for `data:`

Documentation quote:

> The webRequest API only exposes requests that the extension has permission to see, given its host permissions. Moreover, only the following schemes are accessible: `http://`, `https://`, `ftp://`, `file://`, `ws://` (since Chrome 58), `wss://` (since Chrome 58), or `chrome-extension://`.

I'm pretty sure there's already a feature request for this, but I can't currently find it.

Comment: so it's impossible to capture？

Comment: No. I guess it's not that easy for them to implement the feature: judging by https://crbug.com/130065#c3 data urls are handled in a different code path.

Comment: @riskers Added documentation quote with the help of wOxxOm's link; yes, it's currently impossible.