# Offline First! Can't inject Chrome extension code into Offline pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want my content script of chrome extension to atleast load on the below page.

URL of this page is normal url of any website just WIFI is switched off or change the user network to offline from the developers tools.

[image]

Comment: How you are injecting the CS? Can you please share your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error page is displayed via `data:text/html,chromewebdata` URL which you can see by typing `location.href` in devtools console and its Sources panel.

The `data:` scheme is [not scriptable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns), there's nothing you can do about it AFAIK.
Even webRequest API [can't intercept it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45756205).

Comment: I want to themify this page and build a chrome extension over it which can replace or give this page a better look and feel. I have done the POC for this with appending HTML and CSS but didn't consider that chrome extension would have some blockers for this.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwKRQpiClfAaZmppc1A2Z3phb1E/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwKRQpiClfAadktPbUFNZGl5Vms/view?usp=sharing

Anyways thanks :)

Comment: You can do it locally by reassembling resources.pak in chrome installation directory (on each browser update) using [grit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478264/how-to-open-unpack-the-resources-pak-file-of-google-chrome).

Comment: @wOxxOm, Did the Chrome team mention a reason for this yet-another-weird-bug? If our chrome extension is supposed to run when the user is offline, and we inject code into our own `mysite.com`, that extension becomes unusable if the user is offline... sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Btw is there any way to change the user setting for `Offline Auto-Reload Mode` and `Only Auto-Reload Visible Tabs` in about:flags?